# Extend jquery $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

How to just extend selector from $(this) to, lets say, it's children? Or to anything else. I mean, how to properly contcatenate them with $(this)?

Like:

```
$("li.nav").each(function() {
    $(this AND children of this, or this AND it's siblings).something();
});
```

Sorry if this was already answered, couldn't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andself) to accomplish this:

```
$(this).children().andSelf().something();
```

You can also use [`.end`](http://api.jquery.com/end) to pop the last filtering operation off of the current chain. So if you wanted children *and* siblings, you could accomplish that too:

```
$(this)
    .children()    // children of "this"
    .end()         // now we're back to "this"
    .siblings()    // siblings of "this"
    .andSelf()     // and "this" itself
    .something();
```

Comment: Ha ha, this was quickest so far. Thanks!